# Purpose of daemon thread that‘s sleeping indefinitely

Tags: java

I‘m in the process of reverse engineering a program written in the *Java* language. So far, everything‘s making sense, except for a single segment of code that I don‘t comprehend at all. The program itself is a server for the popular game *Minecraft*, although I strongly think that this issue is not related to it per se. Let me show you what I‘m actually talking about:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException cause)
        {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, "Sleeper") {{
    this.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    this.setDaemon(true);
    this.start();
}};
```

And I‘m not talking about the odd `{{` instance initialiser segment down there. It’s about the purpose of the thread in the first place. Is there any reason for it to actually exist? And what would that be?

Comment: There is really no context to work with, so I don't think the question is suited for SO. This is why comments are good for humans

Comment: I agree. I just think that there should be awareness raised towards this particular bug in the `JVM`. It doesn‘t just affect this particular program. It affects every program that does any sort of time based computations.

Comment: Why is the sleep time in hexadecimal? Same with the priority, why? And whatrs going on with the `θ`. Looks like the goal of the author was to do some code golf...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a lot of digging and asking around on various forums, I actually found something that looks quite promising. It all boils down to this particular issue here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6435126.

Let me try to describe what’s actually going on here. I‘ll try my best, although I‘m not entirely sure that I understood this bug entirely.

What‘s happening there seems to be that the `VM` is not initialising correctly. This bug seems to there for quite some time now and fixing it would likely create more problems for existing software than it would actually resolve. The bug itself is related to the inaccuracy of timing functions such as `System.nanoTime()` while `Thread#sleep(long)` is invoked, causing the returned `long` to be off by quite a significant margin.